# If $A$, $B$, and $C$ are three equally likely events, what is the smallest value for $P(A)$ such that $P(A \cap B \cap C)$ always exceeds $0.95$?

Tags: probability

So far I have tried to used the inequality $P(A\cap B \cap C) \geq 1 - P(A^*) - P(B^*) - P(C^*)$. Additionally, since $A$, $B$, and $C$ are equally likely, I know that $-P(A^*) - P(B^*) - P(C^*) = -1/3P(A^*)$. Applying this, and then the relation $P(A) = 1 - P(A^*)$, I get the result $P(A)= 0.85$ however this is incorrect. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please read this [tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.  Does $A*$ mean the complement of $A$?

Comment: $P(A \cap B \cap C)$ must be less or equal then $P(A)$ so $P(A) \ge  .95$.  If $P(A)$ and $P(B)$ and $P(C)$ are all .85 and independent then $P(A \cap B \cap C) = .85^3 = .614$.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig I will have a look! and yes, A* does mean the complement of A.

Answer (score 1):

You made an arithmetic mistake: $-P(\overline{A})-P(\overline{B})-P(\overline{C}) = -3P(\overline{A}).$